# Objectlistview filter combine CompositeAllFilter and CompositeAnyFilter

Tags: filter, objectlistview

i have a objectListView as treeview and i want to filter the list.
The Problem is i have alot of Checkboxes and i need the AND or OR condition.

Here is the code i took form the example project:

```
// Build a composite filter that unify the three possible filtering criteria

List<IModelFilter> filters = new List<IModelFilter>();

if (this.checkBoxHighPriority.Checked)
    filters.Add(
        new ModelFilter(delegate(object model) 
        { 
            return ((ServiceTask)model).Priority > 3; 
        }));

if (this.checkBoxIncomplete.Checked)
    filters.Add(
        new ModelFilter(
            delegate(object model) 
            { 
                return ((ServiceTask)model).Status != ServiceTask.TaskStatus.Complete; 
            }));

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBoxFilter.Text))
    filters.Add(
        new TextMatchFilter(this.olvTasks, this.textBoxFilter.Text));

olvTasks.AdditionalFilter = filters.Count == 0 ? null : new CompositeAllFilter(filters);
```

I can change from `CompositeAllFilter` to `CompositeAnyFilter`, but I want a combination of both:

Something like that:

```
olvTasks.ModelFilter = new ModelFilter(delegate (object x)
{
    var myNode = x as Node;
    return x != null && ((myNode.Status == "0" || myNode.Status == "1" || myNode.Status == 2"|| myNode.Status == "4") && myNode.Breakdown == "True");
}
```

If I only have 4-5 combo boxes it's easy, but I have 10 combo boxes.

How can i compare the filters?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't really understand where the problem is.  It seems like a logic problem and not a coding problem.  Could you please provide more details on how your filters are expected to work together?

Comment: Hi, i added the Excel filter. Now i can filter what i want. It is the easiest way. Thanks